# Deep Learning: Why does the accuracy gets better as batch size decreases?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

My understanding about batch size was the the smaller, the noisier and the less computationally efficient, however I developed a model and I'm using a certain dataset in which I try different configurations, and all I can see is that the accuracy gets better as the batch size decreases (while keeping the rest of the parameters constant). I tried batch sizes of 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 and 64. I expected that the accuracy would increase from 2-8, and it would be stable/oscillating in the others, but the improvement over the reduction of the batch size is totally clear (2 times 5-fold cross-validation).

My question is, why is this happening? What can I say about my model and dataset when this is happening?

Comment: The "why" is a theoretical question, not a programming one. It has to do with flat vs sharp minima. So its offtopic for SO.

Comment: See this - https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/164876/130598

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that it is harder to overfit due to *gradient noise*. But it is not only improving. See Table 5.9 on page 59 of [Analysis and Optimization of Convolutional Neural Network Architectures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf). If you make too small batch sizes, the accuracy decreases again.

Comment: Interesting. I think I am understanding now the theoretical reason, but in my case, I use batches of 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 and 64 and the accuracy is decreasing so I'm getting my highest accuracy when batch size is 2. I expected to have something similar to the table. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understand it.

1. When the batch size is small , the gradients are generally bigger and chaotic. This is because a incorrect value in one of the data point prediction could lead a larger loss when batch size is 2 as compared to 4 (or 16 as compared to 32). This makes the model move closer towards the local optima of that one particular batch at a time.
2. As you train your model, you will realize that the accuracy really doesn't get any better after lesser number of epoch , that is becuase , after sometime these sporadic changes in the value of gradients doesn't work. we need a bigger batch for our model to generalize well quickly.

So, small batches will give fast gradient updates, but the accuracy will stagnate quickly. Larger batches will increase the accuracy very slowly , but will keep doing it for longer number of epochs and will lead to better overall accuracy in longer term.

This is why batch_size is also a hyperparameter and needs to be tuned.

In practice, I have changed the batch_size mid training to gain these benefits but frankly it is almost never worth it. Just run your epoch on somewhat optimal batch_size.